# Click on input levels up the footer on the keyboard whitout change the view ! Cordova jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, keyboard

I'm making an hybrid mobile app using Cordova 2.7. 
I have a header, a content and a footer containing a button.
But, when i click on an input, the mobile keyboard comes up, leveling up the footer also. But if the input clicked is positionned behind the button of the footer, it does as if I clicked on the button ! So I can't stay focus on my input !

Do you have any idea to fix it ??

[image: http://www.casimages.com/img.php?i=131105042806523197.png]

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution :

```
  var initialScreenSize = window.innerHeight; 
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
   if(window.innerHeight < initialScreenSize){
        $("footer").hide(); 
   } else{ 
        $("footer").show(); } });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you set the height of the viewport?
If not then please set the height and width of the viewport as follows.It will scroll your webview to up so that you can write on the text field.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1,
        width=device-width, height=device-height" />
```

and also do not forget to change the preference 'KeyboardShrinksView' to false in config.xml file.